# Set button background image with aspect fit

Tags: swift, button

I have an image that I downloaded from a url. I want to insert that image into a button and use aspect fit so the image looks correct. I need to use a button so a function can be called when selected. I tried two different methods of showing the image, none of which worked:

At first I tried setting the background image. When I ran the simulator the image showed but was not aspectfit, it was stretched and filled the whole contents of the button.

```
let url = URL(string: two2)
    print("Url: \(url!)")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error)
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           let pim = UIImage(data: data!)
           self.centernavlogo.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
           self.centernavlogo.setBackgroundImage(pim, for: .normal)
        }

    }).resume()
```

[result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ESAY.png)

and then I tried this, I tried setting the button image instead of the bachground image. When I ran the simulator there was a little white box inside the button. I tried changing the tint color to see if the button was changing the pictures color but that did not work.

```
let url = URL(string: two2)
    print("Url: \(url!)")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error)
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let pim = UIImage(data: data!)
            self.centernavlogo.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            self.centernavlogo.setImage(pim, for: .normal)

        }

    }).resume()
```

[result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALehR.png)

Edit:

centernavlogo is a button I dragged into the center of the Navigationbar in the storyboard.

```
@IBOutlet weak var centernavlogo: UIButton!
```

Comment: Have you tried to hard-code first? It means you download that image and put into the resource, and use directly, so we can narrow down the issue. And can you update, what the `centernavlogo` is, how it's margin? (it's better if the name is "centerNavLogo")

Comment: @t4nhpt I have not tried to do "hard-code", could you show me what that would look like? Also, I updated my answer to show what the centernavlogo is.

Comment: Well, I meant, you should download the image, put it into the `xcassets` file, and set `self.centernavlogo.image = UIImage(named: "downloadedImage")`. Something like that...

Comment: @t4nhpt How would I save the image to the xcassets?